# Brightness controls act different after waking from suspend on dual-boot Macbook Air 6.1

Tags: suspend, brightness, 16.10, macbook-air

This appears to be a variation on the venerable "why-don't-brightness-controls-work-after-resume?" issue, but with an interesting twist.

The behaviour described below occurs on a [Macbook Air 6.1](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i7-1.7-11-mid-2013-specs.html) with an absolutely stock install of 16.10 (literally the only changes are to reboot, run `sudo apt-get update` and to change the power settings so that closing the lid triggers suspend).

### Description

- After boot (good!):

  - pre-boot brightness level is retained, and
  - brightness controls work as expected.
- After wake (not good!):

  - pre-suspend brightness level is forgotten, and
  - brightness controls work poorly (see below).

### To reproduce

1. Boot.
2. Increase & decrease brightness. Observe.
3. Suspend (either by closing the lid or via the UI).
4. Wake.
5. Increase & decrease brightness. Observe.

### Results

#### Normal brightness control

At step 2, brightness controls work correctly in every way. I can dim the screen through twenty steps from sunburn-bright to off.

#### Broken brightness control

At step 5, brightness controls *do* still work, but:

- brightness is reset to zero (or at least the screen is dark),
- repeatedly tapping brightness fn key returns brightness, but at a very high level.
- there are only four steps of brightness, roughly 'off', 'bright', 'very bright', and 'very, very bright'.

#### Other

Digging around, I noticed I have *two* different items in `/sys/class/backlight` (I have no idea if this is normal):

- `acpi_video0` and
- `intel_backlight`

The contents of `/sys/class/acpi_video0/brightness` and `/sys/class/intel_backlight/brightness` *both* change when I adjust the screen brightness, `acpi_video0` on a scale of 0-100, and `intel_video` on a (non-linear?) scale from 0-2777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started this as a question, but [found the answer right where I should have been looking for it in the first place](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Wily#Backlight). On my hardware, the kernel module on that page solves every part of the problem I describe here.

May it save somebody else a few hours of futzing around (and also, may it teach me to rtfm!)

Comment: I should add that sometimes when opening the lid of the laptop, the screen remains dark until I press one of the brightness keys. But it's completely usable.